# How to fix NPE in mockitoDeepMock#someMethod() in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

Cant test service due to NullPointerException

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
lateinit var someMock: TypeA

//...
@Test
fun test(){
    service.method(someMock)
}
//...
```

Service.kt

```
fun method(typeA: TypeA){

var a1 = typeA.getA() // Ok

var a = typeA.a // NullPointerException

// But both ok if call in debug variables in IDE
```

}

decompiled java code

```java
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(someMock, "someMock");
  TypeA a = someMock.getA();
  TypeA a1 = someMock.getA();
```

decompiled bytecode the same

Comment: `Cant test service` - why? What's the problem? What error do you see?

Comment: @azizbekian my code fail with NullPointerException on ```java var a = typeA.a // NPE ``` line

Comment: Why do you want to use the not working `typeA.a` if `typeA.getA()` does the same and is working? In java/mockito calling a member directly is not an option either.

Comment: @second it is Kotlin, not java. anyway i cant change code which i have to cover by tests. in source code used standard Kotlin usage like```Kotlin  typeA.a```

Comment: So you are saying the devs themselves couldn't decide whether to use `type.a` or `type.getA()`. In that case you probably can't use a mock (as the vanilla mockito version doesn't have the capabilities to do that).

Comment: @second no, In kotlin getter will be called under the hood, see bytecode. I wrote here in 2 variants: typeA.getA() and typeA.a just for showing issue. That code 100% will work on java, but do not work on Kotling. And i asking why